# Wipe InProcess Neo4j DB after each test

Tags: spring, testing, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm using Spring with a Test-Configuration that gives my an InProcessServer Neo4j Database that i use for testing.
Sadly, after each @Test method, there is still scrap-data in this database.
Is it possible to wipe this DB after each Test-Method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the Session and use `purgeDatabase()` to delete everything from the database-

```
@Autowired
private Session session;

 @After
public void clear() {
   session.purgeDatabase();
}
```

Your config that extends `Neo4jConfiguration` should have

```
    @Override
    @Bean
    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return super.getSession();
    }
```

Comment: Btw: My real mistake was forgetting the @Bean annotation for the neo4jServer method in the configuration. Thus there wasn't really an InProcessServer to be used, i just forgot to turn of my remote server that was then used instead without me noticing.